# flex: creating a component based upon s:VGroup

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to create component:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:VGroup xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <mx:DataGrid id="letDataGrid" width="100%" height="100%" rowCount="5">
        <mx:columns>
            .......
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:Form>
        .......
    </mx:Form>
</s:VGroup>
```

code is placed into `FileName.mxml`. When I'm trying to use it (into `ViewStack`)

```
<s:NavigatorContent label="Blocks"  width="100%" height="100%">
    <comp:FileName/>
</s:NavigatorContent>
```

app is compiled and there's nothing in pane where component should be. Can someone explain me what is done incorrect?

**UPD** if I paste content of `FileName.mxml` in place of `<comp:FileName/>` everything is ok

Comment: Set width and height for the component.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic,have tried `<comp:LetterPane width="100%" height="100%" />` that did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who'll read the question: I now understand where the problemm is. I used wrong namespace. There should be `library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"` instead of `xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"`

Comment: Even then I'm surprised this even compiles: `xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"` is missing and the compiler should complain about it. And if the fx namespace wheren't missing, the compiler should complain that you defined two language namespaces (being `xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"` and `xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"`). Have you set your compiler to 'non-strict'?